# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable and $f>0$. Prove that $\int_a^bf>0$. (Without Measure theory)

Tags: calculus, integration

I've been struggling with this for a while, and I have a couple of leads that kind of got me nowhere:

At first I thought that if $f$ is continuous somewhere then the integral will be $>0$. So, if the integral was $0$ then that would mean it would need to be nowhere continuous. That seemed unlikely to me, but I couldn't prove the existence of a point at which it is continuous.

For the integral to be $0$ it would necessitate that for any sub interval of $[a,b]$ the function's infimum would have to be $0$. Also seems weird for $f>0$. Again, got me nowhere.

I should mention that I'm aware that it's possible to prove this by defining "Measure" and all that, but I don't want to go there. I'm wondering if there are more elementary tools to show the above.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean Riemann integrable?

Comment: I do mean Riemann integrable, thanks. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: If it's Riemann integrable, then it's not nowhere continuous

Comment: @Cocopuffs What? =O

Comment: I was told that by my teaching assistant, but that relied on a theorem involving the definition of Measure 0.

Comment: @Cocopuffs, In fact, it's continuous a.e., but he doesn't want to use that.

Comment: @kahen I searched for it before I posted, didn't find anything - but then again I wasn't very patient and didn't look through many threads..

Comment: I think really the most natural and clear proof is to use the fact that Riemann integrable functions are continuous except on a set of exterior measure 0. It does not take long to prove this theorem.

Comment: OP: The best way to search MSE in my experience is to use google's `site:` functionality. Try clicking [this link](https://www.google.com/search?q=riemann+integral+positive+function+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :) I really did use the site's functionality. Anyway I checked out the link you provided with a similar question, but that one involved $f$ which is continuous, which isn't the case I'm considering.
@user66345 It's just that we were given this question as a *starred* question in our homework assignment, and I'm quite convinced we should be able to solve it without resigning to material not-yet-taught in class.

Comment: If this ends up closed as a duplicate, I encourage you to ask again, put a link to the other question in your new question, and remember to write that you specifically are interested in an answer that doesn't use measure theory.

Comment: Could you please clarify and rewrite, for example the following passage isn't clear to me:"At first I thought that if f is continuous somewhere then the integral will be $>0$. So, if the integral was $0$ then that would mean it would need to be nowhere continuous. That seemed unlikely to me, but I couldn't prove the existence of a point at which it is continuous."
Take $f(x)=0$ then $\int_a^b f(x)=0$ but this is smooth/continuous everywhere.

Comment: @dustanalysis That particular passage is quite clear, since it is already in the context that $f>0$.  If $f(x_0)>0$ and $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $f(x)$ can be bounded away from $0$ on a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: For a bounded function $f$, we define the oscillation of $f$ at $a$ by $$\mathrm{osc}f(a) = \limsup_{x\to a} f(x) - \liminf_{x\to a} f(x). $$ Then it is easy to show that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $\mathrm{osc}f(a) = 0$.

Now let us given $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta > 0$. Then we can find a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$. Thus the set $S = S(\epsilon, \delta)$ denotes the collections of subintervals $I$, formed by the points of $P$, where $\sup_{I} f - \inf_{I} f > \delta$ satisfies

$$ \epsilon > U(f,P)-L(f,P) > \sum_{I\in S} \delta |I| $$

Now, choose $(\epsilon_n, \delta_n)$ such that $\delta_n \downarrow 0$ and

$$ l := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon_n}{\delta_n} < b-a. $$

Choose $r >1$ such that $rl < b-a$. For each closed interval $I \in S(\epsilon_n, \delta_n)$, we choose an open interval $J$ containing $I$ such that $|J| = r|I|$. Finally, let $\mathcal{U}$ be the family formed by collecting all such open intervals $J$. If $f$ has no point of continuity, then each $x \in [a, b]$ is a point where $f$ has positive oscillation and hence lies in some $J\in \mathcal{U}$. Thus $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $[a,b]$, and hence it has a finite subcover. But the sum of the length of the open intervals in that subcover cannot exceed $rl < b-a$, a contradiction! Therefore $f$ must have a point of continuity.

Of course, this proof also hides the idea of measure, though indirectly and elusively.

Comment: Thanks!
I see this question was re-opened somehow. I actually got an answer on the other thread that I opened because this one was wrongfully closed. 
Thanks for the proof, it is a little different than the one I saw on the other thread and very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

What does it mean for it to be Riemann integrable? Why $should$ it be positive?  The Riemann sum is defined as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i) : t_i \in (x_{i+1},x_i)$$
over a partition $a=x_0 <x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n = b$

and what is the Riemann integral?  In essence, we let $n\to \infty$ (our partition becomes very fine).  So essentially your question is logically equivalent to asking why the above sum is always positive, well that's because $f(t_i)>0$, so naturally the sum is too... and the integral version just gives us the best solution (but it will always be positive for the same reason).

Comment: Oh, ... I just realized that your question has little to do with the title.... so you need to change the title.

Comment: well ,the upper sum is always positive but we are interested in the limit, as you know the limit of positives may be zero..

Comment: Can't we also say that the Riemann integral is bounded BELOW by the lower Riemann sum (which is positive for the same reason).  ... notice, I never clearly stated where $t_i$ lies in $(x_{i+1},x_i)$.  We may choose it in the worse possible way (lowest lower bound for the sum) and it's still positive. I think my logic is right, no?

Comment: @dustanalysis By "lower Riemann sum" do you mean "lower Darboux sum"?  There may not be a minimum value to give a lowest possible bound.  How do you know that the infimum of $f$ on $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ is positive?

Comment: $m_i$=inf {$x\in[x_i-1,x_i]$ :f(x)} -- so this corresponds to OP's infimum of every subinterval must be zero.We must somehow contradict this with Riemann integrability..

Comment: If $L(f, P)$ is a lower sum then $$L(f,P) \le \int_a^b f dx.$$ Each lower sum is clearly positive.

Comment: @PeteMarkou Have you actually tried to prove that each lower sum is positive before calling it clear?  This is precisely what OP is asking for.  For instance, if $f(x)=1$ for irrational $x$ and $f(x)=1/n$ for $x=m/n$ (lowest terms), then $f>0$ but no lower sum is positive (of course $f$ is not Riemann-integrable).