# Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable and $f>0$. Prove that $\int_a^bf>0$. (No Measure theory)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[Is the Riemann integral of a strictly positive function positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351157/is-the-riemann-integral-of-a-strictly-positive-function-positive)

This is not a duplicate. I'm specifically interested in a proof ***not*** involving Measure Theory. The thread above uses the fact that $f$ has to be continuous at some point and as such that its intergral is bounded below by a positive value.

The question I posted and that was marked as a duplicate is as follows:

Here's a link to it: [Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be Riemann integrable and $f>0$. Prove that $\int_a^bf>0$. (Without Measure theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357472/let-fa-b-to-mathbb-r-be-riemann-integrable-and-f0-prove-that-int-abf)

"I've been struggling with this for a while, and I have a couple of leads that kind of got me nowhere:

At first I thought that if $f$ is continuous somewhere then the integral will be $>0$. So, if the integral was $0$ then that would mean it would need to be nowhere continuous. That seemed unlikely to me, but I couldn't prove the existence of a point at which it is continuous.

For the integral to be $0$ it would necessitate that for any sub interval of $[a,b]$ the function's infimum would have to be $0$. Also seems weird for $f>0$. Again, got me nowhere.

Thank you!"

If you feel this proof that I'm looking for is impossible to produce, please state why you think so. I have reasons to believe this is feasible (One being as it appeared as a a starred question in my homework assignment when we have only just started learning about integration a few weeks ago).

Edits: Wasn't aware that I could file a claim to re-open a post. I'll keep that in mind.
Also, I feel that the contradiction should come from assuming that $f$ is nowhere continuous, and then somehow show that there exists $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$, contradicting the definition of $f$.

Comment: You shouldn't repost, but ask for reopen your last post. I agree, the answer provided in the other post is not satisfactory. I would have filed for a reopen if i had the privelege to

Comment: The claim follows at once observing that an integrable function on a non-trivial interval has continuity points...but this follows from the fact that the function's set of discontinuities has measure zero and I can't see how to go around this argument from measure theory. I'd really like to see this done.

Comment: I believe you are on the right track.  If it is continuous a point, then there is an interval for which it is positive, and then you are done.

If it is not continuous anywhere, you can show this contradicts your hypothesis of Riemann Integrability.

Comment: (cont.) since a Riemann integrable function is continuous almost everywhere

Comment: @Three Showing it contradicts Riemann Integrability using continuity points is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. (In the sense that you're using Measure theory, not that you can't arrive at a different contradiction using continuity points)

Comment: @AdarHefer, if it is continuous nowhere, you can show the difference of upper and lower Riemann sums are always greater than some epsilon -- contradicting Riemann integrability. See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $x\in[a,b]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define 
$$\omega_n(x):=\sup\{f(y):y\in[a,b]\cap[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]\}-\inf\{f(y):y\in[a,b]\cap[x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}]\}.$$
For every $x\in[a,b]$, $\omega_n(x)$ is non-increasing w.r.t. $n$, so we can define
$$w(x):=\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n(x).$$
It is easy to see that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $w(x)=0$.

We claim that(in fact, the set below is of full Lebesgue measure in $[a,b]$) 
$$\{x\in[a,b]:\omega(x)=0\} \text{ is nonempty}.$$
If this is proved, then $f$ has some continuous point, and hence from $f>0$ we will see $\int_a^bf(x)dx>0$.

Let us prove the claim. Denote $O_f:=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$. We may assume that $f$ is not constant, i.e. $O_f>0$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, denote
$$E_n:=\{x\in[a,b]:\omega(x)\le \frac{O_f}{n}\}.$$
If we can find a sequence of decreasing closed intervals $\{I_n\subset[a,b]\}_{n\ge 1}$, such that $E_n\supset I_n$, $\forall n$, then we are done, because
$$\{x\in[a,b]:\omega(x)=0\}=\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n\supset\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n\ne\emptyset. $$

Let us construct $I_n\subset[a,b]$ inductively. By definition, $E_1=[a,b]$, so we can choose $I_1=[a,b]$. Once $I_n:=[a_n,b_n]$ is constructed, then since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $I_n$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$, such that for the partition defined by $t_i=a_n+\frac{i}{m}(b_n-a_n)$, $i=0,1,\dots,m$, the difference between upper Darboux sum and lower Darboux sum is
$$\frac{b_n-a_n}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (\sup_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}f(x))\le\epsilon.$$

In particular, there exists $1\le i\le m$, such that
$$\sup_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}f(x)-\inf_{x\in[t_{i-1},t_i]}f(x)\le \frac{\epsilon}{b_n-a_n}.$$
Note that when $x\in(t_{i-1},t_i)$, the left hand side of the inequality above is no less than $\omega(x)$. Therefore, if we choose $\epsilon=\frac{(b_n-a_n)O_f}{n+1}$ and $m$ accordingly, then $\omega(x)\le\frac{O_f}{n+1}$, $\forall x\in(t_{i-1},t_i)$. As a result, if we choose $I_{n+1}$ to be any closed subinterval of $(t_{i-1},t_i)$, then $I_{n+1}\subset E_{n+1}$, which completes the induction.

Comment: Hey Richard! Thank you very much for your answer. I just have a couple of questions if you'll indulge me:
1. Why does such an $1\le i \le m$ exist?
2. I think I understand why the left hand side of the inequality bounds $\omega (x)$ from above but I'm not sure.

Comment: @AdarHefer: 1. If a function is Riemann integrable, then any Riemann sum converges to the integral as the maximal length of the subintervals(i.e. $\frac{b_n-a_n}{m}$ in this case) in the partition tends to $0$. In particular, the difference between upper Darboux sum and lower Darboux sum converges $0$ as $m\to\infty$. 2.  $\omega(x)\le \omega_k(x)$ for every $k$, and when $k$ is large, $[x-\frac{1}{k},x+\frac{1}{k}]\subset[t_{i-1},t_i]\Rightarrow \omega_k(x)\le$ the left hand side.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!!

Comment: @AdarHefer: You are welcome!